# How to find all minima, maxima, largest and smallest elements of in a partially ordered set $S=\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

As the title suggests; how do I find the all minima, maxima, largest and smallest elements of in a partially ordered set
$$S=\mathbb{N}$$
with the "Divisibility relation" 
$$a\preceq b: \Leftrightarrow a|b$$

And how can I prove that they are correct?

Answer (score 1):

A minimal element $m$ is one such that $a\preceq m$ implies $a=m$. Therefore $1$ is the only minimal element.

A maximal element $m$ is one such that $m\preceq b$ implies $m=b$. As we can pick $b=2m$, there is no maximal element.

A largest element $m$ is one such that $a\preceq m$ for all $a$. Again, trying $a=2m$, we see than there is no largest element.

A smallest element $m$ is one such that $m\preceq b$ for all $b$. Therefore $1$ is the only smallest element.

---

The problem gets a bit more interesting if we consider $\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}$ instead of $\Bbb N$

Comment: Some people consider $0$ to be a natural number. In that case, it is the largest, for this order relation.